# Creating data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I would like to create a new data type that either takes in Start or A tuple of values. This is what I have:

```
type Coord = (Int, Int)
data Direction = N | E | S | W
                 deriving (Eq, Show, Read)


type Move = (Coord, Direction)
type BoardSpec = [(Coord, Bool)]

type GameTreeNode = (GameTree2, BoardSpec, Move)
data GameTree2 = Start | GameTreeNode deriving(Show)


blahblah :: GameTree2
blahblah = blahb

blahb :: GameTreeNode
blahb = (Start, testbo, ((1, 1), N))
```

This however, gives me the error on blahblah

```
Couldn't match type `(GameTree2, Move)' with `GameTree2'
Expected type: GameTree2
  Actual type: GameTreeNode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>data GameTree2 = Start | GameTreeNode deriving(Show)</strike>

expands to:

```
data GameTree2 = Start | (GameTree2, BoardSpec, Move) deriving(Show)
```

You can't make a tuple a valid value of your type.

---

You need to wrap it in a constructor:

```
data GameTree2 = Start | Node GameTreeNode deriving(Show)
```

where `Node` is whatever name you choose for it.

Comment: The proposed solution is nice, but the explanation of what went wrong is not correct. `data GameTree2 = Start | GameTreeNode` does not expand at all; it simply defines a new name `GameTreeNode` at the term level that is completely distinct from the `GameTreeNode` that exists at the type level.

Comment: @DanielWagner oh my, what an oversight on my part.